# merge results from ajax to source of autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
    }).focus();

    $.ajax({
        url: "source.php",
        success: function(result) {
            return result;
            //["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
        }
    });

});
```

**Question: how to replace static source in autocomplete with ajax results ?**

Idea:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: //result from ajax function
}).focus();
```

**Source.php** (just example)

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM tags");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $results[] = $row['name'];
}

echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: Michal, I guess that depends on what's the response from the ajax request

Comment: @Leo I put response from ajax in comment (under result). It is same as static defined data in source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Declare a *global array variable* and change there values, whenever required.

```
var languages = $.ajax({
        url: "source.php",
        success: function(result) {
            return result;
            //["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
        }
    });

$("#search").autocomplete({
        source: languages
    }).focus();
```

2) or combine [**ajax with autocomplete**](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

```
$(function () {
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "source.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    return data;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concat the two arrays (the first list of words and the one you receive by ajax) and then call .autocomplete() again;

```
var words = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
$(function() {
    /** This part is only necessary if the ajax does not fire immediately when the page is loaded **/
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: words
    }).focus();
    /** end of what I said above **/
    $.ajax({
        url: "source.php",
       success: function(result) {
            words = words.concat(result);
            $("#search").autocomplete({
                source: words
            }).focus();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should user [function as a source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) with two arguments:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "source.php",
            data: {query: request.term},
            success: function(result) {
                response(result);
            }
        });
    }
}).focus();
```

If you type "php" in the field, it will issue an ajax request to the `source.php?query=php`.

Comment: I added source.php so you can see, that I don't parse arguments to source.php. I just simply echo results as data for `source` in `autocomplete` function.

Comment: Why do you need ajax autocomplete then? You can simply preload this data with page load and to have it immediately. Anyway, just don't use `data` parameter.